# Prevent animation when mat-slide-toggle is added with ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In my angular app, I have a settings page where user can check several options. I use `mat-slide-toggle` for all options.

```
<div *ngFor="let setting of visibleSettings">
    <div style="display: flex;">
        <div>
            <p class="setting-name">{{setting.name}}</p>
            <p class="setting-description">{{setting.def.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 1;"></div>
        <mat-slide-toggle
                class="toggle-setting"
                name="{{setting.name}}"
                [ngModel]="setting.value"
                (change)="onSettingChanged(setting, $event)">
        </mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
</div>
```

`visibleSettings` member is initialized with a copy of current setting values, and all changes done by user are reflected in this copy. User can discard or save changes after modifying settings. Whenever user discards or saves changes, `visibleSettings` gets re-initialized with a copy of latest settings.

When `visibleSettings` gets re-initialized, the slide toggles which should be in checked state initially becomes unchecked, and then it gets checked with an animation. This is a distraction to the user, since whenever user saves or discards, the settings which were checked get unchecked for a moment and gets checked again.

Is there any way to prevent this and make slide toggles to stay in the state specified by the `[ngModel]="setting.value"` whenever the `visibleSettings` gets re-initialized?

Comment: Have you tried binding the slide-toggle to checked instead of using ngModel? Usually, [ngModel] goes hand-in-hand with (ngModelChange) for use in template driven forms. Slide toggle has its own counterparts [checked] and (change) which are for use without a form. I suspect mixing the two separate models could be your issue.

Comment: @G.Tranter your solution worked. Please post as an answer so I can accept

Comment: I have the same problem. I use ngFor to bind my model which is an object (via the keyvalue pipe). But the problem is that I can't use checked because it's unidirectional. I need to know the values of the toggles and the Checked property does not bind the values to my model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try binding the slide-toggle to checked instead of using ngModel. Usually, [ngModel] goes hand-in-hand with (ngModelChange) for use in template driven forms. Slide toggle has its own counterparts [checked] and (change) which are for use without a form. I suspect mixing the two separate models could be your issue.